# Response not displayed in the view (nodejs, mysql, angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to populate a basic angular app with data from a database. Example similar to that in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_customers_mysql). This is the code so far:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
            <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.appid }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>    

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:3000/test")
            .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;}); 
        });
</script>
```

However, no data are retrieved. The response i get from http://localhost:3000/test is the following:

> [
>
> {"id":1,"appid":1},{"id":2,"appid":1},{"id":7,"appid":1},
>   {"id":20,"appid":1},{"id":38,"appid":1},{"id":39,"appid":1},{"id":40,"appid":1},{"id":41,"appid":3},{"id":44,"appid":3},{"id":70,"appid":2},{"id":71,"appid":2},{"id":72,"appid":2}
>
> ]

I checked it both from the browser and from postman. If I replace response.data.records with the response above, the table displays the values in the response.

I know I must be messing something up, but somehow I am missing it. My best guess would be that of the format of the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `.records` from the `respnse.data`

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/test")
        .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data;});
```

Since you are directly receiving an array just assign array from response directly to `$scope.names`.

Comment: What a coincidence, I just figured it out. Anyway I got it via trial and error so thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

According to your shown data your issue should be solved when you replace

```
$scope.names = response.data.records;
```

with

```
$scope.names = response.data;
```

because your sample response is just an array without being wrapped within a `record` property.